# How to increase the progress refresh rate when downloading a file from AWS S3 on Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my Android app, I'm downloading a file from AWS S3:

```java
TransferUtility transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
                .context(this)
                .s3Client(amazonS3Client)
                .defaultBucket("my-bucket")
                .build();

File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.ogg");
TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.download("file.ogg", myFile);
transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state)
    {
        idDernierDownload = id;
        Flog.d("onStateChanged: " + id + ", " + state);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal)
    {
        Flog.d("id = " + id + " : " + bytesCurrent + " / " + bytesTotal);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int id, Exception e)
    {
        Flog.e("id = " + id + " : Erreur : " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

My problem is that `onProgressChanged()` is called every 2 seconds or so, which is quite a low rate.

Is it possible then to increase that rate to something like 3 times per second?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs, a TransferObserver gives access to the state as well as an option for a transfer listener. Perhaps you can query the state directly in the TransferObserver object from an independent thread or equivalent?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, I tried something similar, like a timer that calls `transferObserver.getBytesTransferred()` 4 times per second, but it only returns the last value that you get in `onProgressChanged()`, so it doesn't help, unfortunately...

Comment: I see, good that you tried it. I'm not aware of more fine-grained progress unfortunately.

Comment: The workaround I just found is to call, in a timer, `myFile.length()` instead of `transferObserver.getBytesTransferred()`. But I'm still interested in a cleaner solution, though...